# How to put an interface in a generic dynamically?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following test class:

```
public class OutsideClass
{
    private List<Type> _interfaces = null;

    public void InjectInterfaces(Type[] types)
    {
        if(_interfaces == null)
        {
            _interfaces = new List<Type>();
        }

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            if(type.IsInterface)
            {
                _interfaces.Add(type);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PerformSomethingWithTheInterfaces()
    {
        foreach (var i in _interfaces)
        {
            new Test<i>().PerformSomething(); // On this line the error occurs
        }
    }
}

internal class Test<T>
{
    internal void PerformSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

This gives me on  however the message `Type or namespace name expected`. How can I adjust this code so that it works?

What I am trying to do is to pass in a bunch of interfaces to a class library, there loop over the interfaces and use **Unity** to Resolve, based on the interface, something. I use the Resolve extension method.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use reflection... something like this:

```
foreach (Type type in _interfaces)
{
    Type concreteType = typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
    MethodInfo method = concreteType.GetMethod("PerformSomething",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);
    method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

(You may need to make minor changes - the above isn't tested or even compiled.)

With C# 4 and dynamic typing, you can make it somewhat simpler:

```
foreach (Type type in _interfaces)
{
    Type concreteType = typeof(Test<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
    dynamic d = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);
    d.PerformSomething();
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks daunting but I will give it a try. Thanks for trying to help me out on this one.

Comment: Of course, this (or something very close to it) will work.  But I'm wondering what the intent is on the part of the OP.  I get the feeling you just gave a right answer to the wrong question (and so did I, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass values as generic arguments.  Only types.  To be clear:

typeof(string) != string.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you called a string is not a `System.String`, but rather a C# token.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can work.  You specialize a generic statically on the type name.  You can't pass in a reference to the `Type` object.

There are ways to do what you want, but they involve C# 4 and `DynamicObject`.

Comment: Skeet's answer is right, of course, although he's using reflection outright instead of the hidden reflection of `dynamic`.  I prefer the latter, because it makes it possible to make `PerformSomethingWithTheInterfaces` dynamic.

Comment: I am still on .NET 3.5 unfortunately. However for future reference do you have some sample with DynamicObject?

Comment: You still need to use reflection even with dynamic typing, in order to create the instance of `Test<T>`.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, but I'm not clear on what exactly the *point* of `Test<T>` is.

Comment: @Nyla: Actually, the example on the reference page is pretty good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might really want to look at C# 4's MEF just as an idea as a unity replacement I think it stands up really well myself and simplifies the resolution mechanisms a lot, and may give functionality to complete the task you're attempting more simply..

```
namespace MEF_Interface
{
    // Interface to recognize the concrete implementation as
    public interface IMessageWriter
    {
        void WriteMessage();
    }

}

namespace MEF_HelloMessageWriter
{
    // Concrete implementation in another assembly
    [Export(typeof(IMessageWriter))]
    public class HelloMessageWriter : IMessageWriter
    {
        public void WriteMessage() { Console.WriteLine("Hello!"); }
    }
}

namespace MEF_GoodbyeMessageWriter
{
    // Concrete implementation in another assembly
    [Export(typeof(IMessageWriter))]
    public class GoodbyeMessageWriter : IMessageWriter
    {
        public void WriteMessage() { Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!"); }
    }
}

namespace MEF_Example
{
    class DIContainer
    {
        [Import]
        public IMessageWriter MessageWriter { get; set; }

        public DIContainer(string directory)
        {
            // No more messy XML DI definition, just a catalog that loads
            // all exports in a specified directory. Filtering is also available.
            DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directory);
            catalog.Refresh();
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string helloMessageWriterPath =
                @"C:\shared\Projects\MEF_Example\MEF_HelloMessageWriter\bin\Debug";

            string goodbyeMessageWriterPath =
                @"C:\shared\Projects\MEF_Example\MEF_GoodbyeMessageWriter\bin\Debug";

            DIContainer diHelloContainer = new DIContainer(helloMessageWriterPath);
            diHelloContainer.MessageWriter.WriteMessage();

            DIContainer diGoodbyeContainer = new DIContainer(goodbyeMessageWriterPath);
            diGoodbyeContainer.MessageWriter.WriteMessage();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but I'm not sure it relates to the OP.  Then again, I don't really understand the OP, so I could very easily be mistaken.

Comment: That's kind of how I felt. I'm not sure the OP knows what he wants to do, so this might help.

Comment: @Jimmy: Please prefix your comments with "@" and the username.  Otherwise, they won't get notified (unless it's their question or answer).

Comment: Anyhow, yeah, I'm at a loss as to intent, but there doesn't seem to be any follow-up from the OP, so I'm going to give up.

Comment: It sure does look interesting. I am still on 3.5 so is there a version for 3.5 as well? @Steve, I am just trying something. I found some code lying around which uses the Resolve<T> extension method. I was just trying to make up something for a test as I am still very new to dependency injection and that is how I cooked up my example.

Comment: @Nyla: Well, the release is for 4.0, but there's a 3.5 version at http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/48222.  It looks like Resolve<T> is from Unity or something similar.  Looking at http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/ExtendUnityUnityContainerExtensionMethodsCSharp3.aspx, it seems that it's doing something closer to what Jimmy showed than you originally asked about.  In particular, it does not require either reflection or `dynamic`.